# What is the encoding of the string get from StreamReader.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, unicode, streamreader

First, let's see the code:

```
//The encoding of utf8.txt is UTF-8
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\\utf8.txt", Encoding.UTF8, true);
while (reader.Peek() > 0)
{
    //What is the encoding of lineFromTxtFile?
    string lineFromTxtFile = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

As Joel said in his famous [article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html):

> If you have a string, in memory, in a file, or in an email message, you have to know what encoding it is in or you cannot interpret it or display it to users correctly."

So here comes my question: what is the encoding of the string **lineFromTxtFile**? UTF-8(because it is from a text file encoded in UTF-8)? or UTF-16(because string in .NET is "Unicode"(UTF-16))?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.NET strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) are Unicode. Encoding doesn't play a part, then until you need to use it next. If you go to write it out to a file, for example, then you will specify the output encoding. But since .NET handles everything you do with the string via library calls, it doesn't matter how it's represented in memory.

Comment: So if I want dump this string to a file, `StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\unicide.txt",false, Encoding.Unicode);writer.WriteLine(lineFromTxtFile )`?

Comment: @jjooeell The encoding you give to the stream writer has no relevance to how that string was stored in memory. It is used to convert characters into bytes, not bytes to bytes.

Comment: Agreed. The encoding you specify there tells how it ends up being written to disk, not what is already in memory.

Comment: This answer isn't very accurate, all unicode strings are encoded.  Utf16 for .NET strings, least-endian on most machines.

Answer (score 6):

All .Net string variables are encoded with [Encoding.Unicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx) (**UTF-16, little endian**). Even better, because you know your text file is utf-8 and told your streamreader the correct encoding in the constructor, any special characters will be handled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It would be Unicode, because all .NET strings are. Real question: why does it matter?

Comment: To prove these codes are not necessary:`byte[] dataByte = .Encoding.UTF8GetBytes(lineFromTxtFile);string strOutLine = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(dataByte);`

Comment: @jjooeell I am not sure what are you saying.

Comment: because `lineFromTxtFile` is already a "Unicode"(UTF-16) string, so conversion(UTF-8-->byte[]-->UTF-16) is not necessary.